# How to deploy HTML webpages from IIS?

Tags: html, iis-7

I have developed some webpages and all the web pages are working fine, Now I need to deploy in my `localhost`. How can I do this?

I tried by creating a virtual directory and copied the HTML pages, CSS, JS and images in the virtual directory but this is not working, It shows

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

My default webpage name is 'index.html'

Answer (score 3):

You need to point your IIS virtual directory to the physical location of your sites files. This can be anywhere on your machine.

It is common for a website to physically live in disk:\inetpu\websites\ under its own directory.

A virtual directory is just that, it doesn't physically exist on your machine.

You should then be able to browse to your site as follows:

```
http://localhost/virtualdirectory/index.html
```